# How to import all files in folder with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I use js in nodeJS I could require any file like below

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readDirSync('/dir/name')
.forEach(dir => require(dir))
```

how could I do the same thing with typescript?

```
import fs from 'fs'
fs.readDirSync('/dir/name')
.forEach(dir => import dir)
```

Comment: what's the purpose of these imports? You can't even use them as you have no references to the modules you imported.

Answer (score -1):

Typescript does not change the way you use any function or statement.
It adds extra features to add Types.

Can you provide more information?

How are trying to run or compile the TypeScript code.

---

```
import fs from 'fs'
fs.readDirSync('/dir/name')
.forEach(dir => import(dir).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}))
```

Comment: I can use require in typescript like this
import fs from 'fs'
fs.readDirSync('/dir/name')
.forEach(dir => import dir)

Comment: Use -> import("/dir/name").then(file=> {
     //do whatever you want
    });